# How to make three circles responsive with change in screen size in Angular2 application?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a div in which I have three circles (I have used *ngFor as data is coming from an API). I want these three circles to be inline and responsive with the change in screen size using bootstrap only. I want to avoid using a media query.

Here is my HTML code:--

```
<div class="container-fluid non_circleRowCss ">
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-12"> </div>      
        <div *ngFor = "let OverviewQuestionText of career_Results.OverviewQuestionText; let i = index " class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-12 non_circleCSS "[style.backgroundColor] = colorsArray[i]>
             <div class="text01">
               {{OverviewQuestionText.OverviewQuestion }}
             </div>                                                                               
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-12"> </div>         
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS I used on one of the column to create a circle:

```
.non_circleCSS {
    min-width: 253px;
     min-height: 253px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 122px;   
    -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
     display: table; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({ selector: '[myHighlight]' })
export class makeMyDivAPerfectAndResponsiveCircle{
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
       let myWinSize=document.width;
       el.nativeElement.style.width= myWinSize;
        //...Etc to make a circle
    }
}
```

Perhaps you might have to inject the document or get the "width" another way.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#write-directive